# Why expression fails in init file, but works fine during session

Tags: init-file, themes, debugging, start-up

I want to understand why an expression of the form

```
(load-theme 'my-kewl-theme t)
```

fails<sup>1</sup> when run as the last expression in my init (`~/.emacs`) file, but works fine if I evaluate it as soon as soon as Emacs' startup is done.

How can I troubleshoot/debug this conundrum?

The only clue I have is that right before `(load-theme 'my-kewl-theme t)` is evaluated ***at the end*** of the loading of `~/.emacs`, the variable `custom-theme-load-path` has the value

```
(custom-theme-load-directory t)
```

whereas after Emacs starts, it has the value

```
("/path/to/my-kewl-theme/" custom-theme-load-directory t)
```

I don't know what accounts for this difference.  (This variable is not referred to at all by `~/.emacs`, at least explicitly.)  The variable `custom-theme-load-directory` has the value `~/.emacs.d` throughout.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>`` error: Unable to find theme file for `my-kewl-theme` ``</sup>

Comment: Without bothering to understand, you could set the variable to include the element `"/path/to/my-kewl-theme/"` as its first element, in your init file before invoking the `load-theme`. You can alternatively try to find the code that (already) adds that path to the value, and evaluate that code before loading the theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the emacs manual regarding packages:

> By default, Emacs also automatically loads all installed packages in
>   subsequent Emacs sessions.  This happens at startup, after processing
>   the init file.

So if your theme relies on some package initialisation you can put your call in `after-init-hook`.  For example

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 
   (lambda ()
     (load-theme 'my-kewl-theme t)))
```

Alternatively, enable the theme by customising `custom-enabled-themes`, instead of using `load-theme` in your init file.

Comment: It turns out that with `after-init-hook` I did not get the same results as with manual evaluation, so instead I ended up adding the hook to `window-setup-hook` (which is triggered after `after-init-hook`), but basically the same idea.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I believe it is standard practice for themes installed as packages to add their own paths to `custom-theme-load-path` as an autoload.  A call to `package-initialize` will execute all of your package autoloads (among other things), and if there isn't an explicit call in your init file, it is called implicitly at the end of initialization.

I recommend putting a `(package-initialize)` towards the beginning of your init file, right after you configure package.el itself (adding repositories, etc.) and before you do anything with any packages not built-in to Emacs itself.